# seamless looping of images in scrolling slideshow banner using css only

Tags: css, scroll, css-animations, slideshow

I got code for a css scrolling slideshow which with the help of Naren Murali I was able to modify for my 14 images, based on the demo which used only 6.  However, the only problem is that I don't know how to modify the keyframe animations so that the 1st and last image are the same, resulting in a seamless transition from the end of the show to the next iteration.

If someone can explain to me how to accomplish this I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

```css
    html {
        background-color: white;
        }
    body {
        width: 1300px;
     margin: 0 auto 0;
        }
    #container {
     width: 500px;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin: 50px auto;
     background: white;
    }
    .photobanner {
        height: 270px;
        width: 6748px;
        margin-bottom: 80px;
        font-size:0px;
    }
    img{
      margin-right:2px;
    }
    .flex-container {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 30px;
        }
    .first {
     -webkit-animation: bannermove 60s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation: bannermove 60s linear infinite;
         -ms-animation: bannermove 60s linear infinite;
          -o-animation: bannermove 60s linear infinite;
             animation: bannermove 60s linear infinite;
    }
    @keyframes "bannermove" {
     0% {
        margin-left: 0px;
     }
     100% {
        margin-left: -6268px;
     }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes bannermove {
     0% {
       margin-left: 0px;
     }
     100% {
       margin-left: -6268px;
     }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
     0% {
       margin-left: 0px;
     }
     100% {
       margin-left: -6268px;
     }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes "bannermove" {
     0% {
       margin-left: 0px;
     }
     100% {
       margin-left: -6268px;
     }
    }
    @-o-keyframes "bannermove" {
     0% {
       margin-left: 0px;
     }
     100% {
       margin-left: -6268px;
     }
    }
    img{
      margin-right:2px;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
    </header>
    <section class="flex-container">
        <div id="container">
         <!-- Each image is 480px by 270px -->
        <div class="photobanner">
         <img class="first" src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_blue.jpg" alt="blue" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_23rd_st.jpg" alt="23rd st" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_broken_guru.jpg" alt="broken guru" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_church_ave.jpg" alt="church ave" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_nose.jpg" alt="nose" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_pants.jpg" alt="pants" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_i_will_miss_you.jpg" alt="i will miss you" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_network_reality_stars.jpg" alt="network reality all stars" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_kline.jpg" alt="kline" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_queen.jpg" alt="queen" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_water.jpg" alt="water" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_swirls.jpg" alt="swirls" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_robins_egg.jpg" alt="robins egg" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_ports.jpg" alt="ports" />
    </div>
        </div>
     </section>
```

Comment: Tip: vendor prefixes for `@keyframes` are not necessary anymore.

Comment: Another tip: If you use `display: flex` (with no wrapping) in the `photobanner` container you shouldn't need to set an absolute width, so you can add new items without needing to edit the CSS.

Comment: Thank you for the tips.  If you have insight into how I make the final image move seamlessly into the first when the cycle completes, I'd appreciate it. In the demo, the author has 6 images and then makes the 1st 4 repeat.  He says this facilitates "repeating enough images to fill the frame."  This enables the "first frame to perfectly match the last frame." I don't understand the metrics and so can't duplicate the process.  Presumably, writing the html this way is somehow tied in with the length of the show, and perhaps the margin-left value in the keyframes?  Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to the demo and figured it out.  I repeated the 1st 4 images after the full cycle of 14.  I made the .container 1000px wide and the .photobanner 8640px wide (480px (width of image) x 18).  Then I set the margin to a negative value to move the line of images left far enough that the second iteration of the first image takes the initial spot.  Since in the demo this number was -2125 and each image had a width of 350px, and 2125 / 350 = 6 which was the number of discrete images, I multiplied my 14 discrete images by 480 = 6720.  This almost aligned but needed tweaking.  With a left margin of -6745, it ran quite smoothly.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    }
.flex-container_1 {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 1200px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    }
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: white;
    }
.photobanner {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 270px;
    width: 8640px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size:0px;
}
img{
  margin-right:2px;
}
.first {
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 60s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: bannermove 60s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: bannermove 60s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: bannermove 60s linear infinite;
            animation: bannermove 60s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
    margin-left: -6745px;
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes bannermove {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -6745px;
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -6745px;
 }
}
@-ms-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -6745px;
 }
}
@-o-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -6745px;
 }
}
img{
  margin-right:2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<section class="flex-container_1">
    <div class="container">
     <!-- Each image is 480px by 270px -->
     <div class="photobanner">
            <img class="first" src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_blue.jpg" alt="blue" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_23rd_st.jpg" alt="23rd st" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_broken_guru.jpg" alt="broken guru" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_church_ave.jpg" alt="church ave" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_nose.jpg" alt="nose" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_pants.jpg" alt="pants" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_i_will_miss_you.jpg" alt="i will miss you" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_network_reality_stars.jpg" alt="network reality all stars" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_kline.jpg" alt="kline" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_queen.jpg" alt="queen" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_water.jpg" alt="water" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_swirls.jpg" alt="swirls" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_robins_egg.jpg" alt="robins egg" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_ports.jpg" alt="ports" />
<img class="first" src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_blue.jpg" alt="blue" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_23rd_st.jpg" alt="23rd st" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_broken_guru.jpg" alt="broken guru" />
            <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_church_ave.jpg" alt="church ave" />
    </div>
        <p>film stills from "wall cuts, train stations, New York City" &#40;2016&#41;</p>
    </div>
      </section>
</html>
```